# How to modify this proof to the case $\partial^2 f$ is not continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, proof-explanation, bilinear-form

I'm reading the proof that continuous second derivative is symmetric

> [image]

In the proof below, the authors utilize the continuity of $\partial^2 f$, but from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3428893/is-this-a-discrepancy-about-the-symmetry-of-second-derivative), I got that we do not need the continuity of $\partial^2 f$.

**My question:** How to modify the below proof to the case $\partial^2 f$ is not continuous? Thank you so much for your help!

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]